# A popup ou O popup?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tradução

Sempre chamei de "o popup", mas não sei qual é o modo correto.

[image: a popup]

Está correto dizer "a popup" ou o correto seria mesmo "o popup"?

Answer (score 7):

Como em inglês os substantivos não têm gênero, não há um referencial inquestionável para se definir como fica a tradução. Acredito que quem traduziu no feminino considerou que a palavra "janela" está subentendida: "a [janela] popup". Se nos pautarmos pelo uso, eu diria que no Brasil é mais comum usarmos "o popup" (que é como soa mais natural para mim).